# R: How can I export methods provided by a package to a PSOCK cluster?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

In `R`, I have a list of matrices and would like to apply a summary function to the matrices in the list. The matrices represent social networks, therefore I need to apply some specialized summary functions provided by the `ergm` package. These summary statistics are contained in a summary method. I can write a function as a wrapper around this summary method and use `lapply` to apply the function to the list of matrices.

However, when I try to parallelize this by using `parLapply` or `parSapply` from the `parallel` package, the results look weird. And when I export the `summary.statistics` function, I even get an error message.

Do I have to export the summary method that is provided by the ergm package to the cluster object? If so, how? The following code is a self-contained example.

```
library("ergm")
library("parallel")

# create list of matrices
m <- matrix(rbinom(900, 1, 0.1), nrow = 30)
l <- list(m, m, m, m, m)

# write wrapper function that computes results
fun <- function(mat) {
  s <- summary(mat ~ edges + dsp(1))
  return(s)
}

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)  # create cluster object

test1 <- sapply(l, fun)  # works!
test2 <- parSapply(cl, l, fun)  # problem: results look weird!

clusterExport(cl, varlist = "summary.statistics")
test3 <- parSapply(cl, l, fun)  # problem: says method is not applicable!
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of exporting functions that are defined in packages, you should load the package in the workers using something like:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library("ergm"))
```

You should always load all of the packages needed by the worker function, since they aren't loaded automatically just because the package has been loaded by the master.